# How do I make this layout?

Tags: html

So my current layout is:

```
<div style="width:900px;height:500px;border:6px double #00c7ff;"><table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0"
 bgcolor="white" id="shell" height="500" width="900">
   <tr height="50">
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#cab0cb">
         <table title="Banner" id="banner" border="0">
            <tr><td>Place a banner here</td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr height="50">
      <td bgcolor="#cab0cb">
         <table id="navigation" title="Navigation" border="0">
            <tr><td><center><b><font face="arial" color="0094bd"><font size="5">Records</font></b></center><br><br><font size="2.5">No records set yet.</font></font></td></tr>

         </table>
      </td><td bgcolor="#cab0cb">
         <table title="Content" id="content" border="0">
            <tr><td><font face="arial" color="#0094bd"><b><font size="5"><center>Welcome to Ivory Forest Kennel</center></font></b><br><br><font size="2.5">We are a fairly new kennel on K9, specialising in the great Siberian Husky. Initially, we will be breeding and selling Huskies, bred from simple gamebred dogs. Our huskies currently specialise in Obedience, but we will seek further training later. Soon, we will also be breeding Yorkshire Terriers, also gamebred, so look forward to those!</font></font></td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And Im trying to make it sort of like these: 
http://i18.photobucket.com/albums/b135/silverfox13425/Decorated%20images/Dexterity_zps04ada334.png
http://i18.photobucket.com/albums/b135/silverfox13425/Decorated%20images/Siberians_zpsbe70e931.png

Which I could be going about it all wrong, to be honest, but it's working thus far.. **My issue at the moment is my "records" section is too thin.** And I cant figure out for the life of me how to make it wider. I have tried editing everything that says "width", and making my own `width=x` sort of command, but nothing seems to be working. No clue what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Show us what you have done at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question: Use CSS and not attributes and inline-style for creating layouts. It is usually discouraged to use table elements for a layout, and use other elements instead that define the structure of your document better. Also please note that html is a **markup** language. There are no *"sort of command(s)"* in html. You simply define how the browser should interpret the layout and how to style it.

Comment: @Sumurai8 is right, you should learn how to use block elements to create a layout instead of HTML tables, tables are mostly suited to display tabular data

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=layout+banner+two+colums+css+html5

Comment: The website doesnt allow CSS. Only HTML. Its not a website, its a layout on a page for that exact site, actually. And, from what Ive gathered, most people who do the layouts there use the tables. I dont know what else to say, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your [**JsBin**](http://jsbin.com/AQovEhA/9/edit) code

Well, I was not supposed to give you some suggestions on your layout.
But I must say

- Your layout is really complicated.
- You should not use too much tables, tables are just used to render some tabular data.
- Try to use only **`<div>`** tags.
- Please use some **`jsbin`** or **`jsfiddle`** like online tools to show us your problems.
- Nesting of tables really creates complexities in your html code thus reduces its readability.

If you feel problems in designing your web page layout then I'll recommend these links to you. Please take a look.

1. http://www.learnlayout.com
2. http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmldiv.php
3. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68kiDajh1lg
4. http://gostats.com/resources/css-div-tutorial.html

### Your code

```
<div style="width:90%; margin:auto;height:500px;border:6px double #00c7ff; vertical-align:top;"><table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="0"
  bgcolor="#cab0cb" id="shell" height="500" >
   <tr height="50">
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#cab0cb">
         <table title="Banner" id="banner" border="0">
            <tr><td>Place a banner here</td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr height="50">
     <td bgcolor="#cab0cb" style="width:20%;">
         <table id="navigation" title="Navigation" border="0">
           <tr><td><center><b><font face="arial" color="0094bd"><font size="5">Records</font></b></center><br><br><font size="2.5">No records set yet.</font></font></td></tr>
          </table>
      </td><td bgcolor="#cab0cb">
         <table title="Content" id="content" border="0">
            <tr><td><font face="arial" color="#0094bd"><b><font size="5"><center>Welcome to Ivory Forest Kennel</center></font></b><br><br><font size="2.5">We are a fairly new kennel on K9, specialising in the great Siberian Husky. Initially, we will be breeding and selling Huskies, bred from simple gamebred dogs. Our huskies currently specialise in Obedience, but we will seek further training later. Soon, we will also be breeding Yorkshire Terriers, also gamebred, so look forward to those!</font></font></td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Danku, friend. but two things. One, from what I gathered, everyone on that site uses tables for the layout. I dont know what else to look to make it look like the others. And two, Im not exactly doing a website - its more like a page. Bound to look nearly like the ones in the question. But that doesnt make your answer unhelpful. the links will surely help a lot, thank you. And I hope you didnt get in trouble for helping if you werent supposed to!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and change your Record field size needed.

> `<td width="20%">`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hacve/1/)

Comment: I will attempt it and report how it goes!

Comment: `@AmandaTima` just change the td width and you change the record field size change